# Tkinter bind return/enter to a button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a button which counts how many times you clicked it. I would like to make it work with return/enter key aswell. Here is my code

```
import Tkinter
window=Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Clicks Counter")
presses=0
def addClick(self):
    global presses
    presses += 1
    lbl.configure(text=presses)
lbl=Tkinter.Label(window, text=presses)
lbl.pack()
btn=Tkinter.Button(window, text="Click Me", command=addClick)
btn.config(font=('helvetic',40))
btn.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

Please suggest how to implement this in the most simplest way

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Thanks to @BryanOakley 's comment. The correct answer would be:

1 -> On the one hand, you could set all events (as `button` as `window` object) with `bind` method, it would be:

```
window.bind('<Return>', addClick)
window.bind('<BackSpace>', addClick)
btn.bind('<Button-1>', addClick)
```

And `addClick` method would be:

```
def addClick(event):
    global presses
    presses += 1
    lbl.configure(text=presses)
```

Code of first option:

```
import Tkinter
window=Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Clicks Counter")

presses=0

def addClick(event): # Change this line!
    global presses
    presses += 1
    lbl.configure(text=presses)

window.bind('<Return>', addClick) # Change this line!
window.bind('<BackSpace>', addClick) # Change this line!

lbl=Tkinter.Label(window, text=presses)
lbl.pack()
btn=Tkinter.Button(window, text="Click Me")
btn.config(font=('helvetic',40))
btn.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

btn.bind('<Button-1>', addClick) # Change this line!

window.mainloop()
```

2 -> On the other hand, you could change the `addClick` method, adding a optional argument as @BryanOakley comments. Then, you would not change the third parameter (`command`) of `Tkinter.Button()`. It would be:

```
def addClick(event=None):
    global presses
    presses += 1
    lbl.configure(text=presses)

window.bind('<Return>', addClick)
window.bind('<BackSpace>', addClick)
```

Code of second option:

```
import Tkinter
window=Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Clicks Counter")
presses=0

def addClick(event=None): # Change this line!
    global presses
    presses += 1
    lbl.configure(text=presses)

window.bind('<Return>', addClick) # Change this line!
window.bind('<BackSpace>', addClick) # Change this line!

lbl=Tkinter.Label(window, text=presses)
lbl.pack()
btn=Tkinter.Button(window, text="Click Me", command=addClick)
btn.config(font=('helvetic',40))
btn.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

I hope that it is that you wanted and thanks to @BryanOakley again :D

Comment: Since bindings pass an `event` argument to the callback, `addClick` will have to be modified to accept this parameter. Since the function is also used for a button callback, the event parameter needs to be optional.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley by that information, it has been helpful :-)

Comment: a better default would be `event=None`.